# parse string into columns

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a column called "name". It is of type string. It looks something like this :

| name |
| --- |
| attr1=val1a; attr2=val2a; attr3=val3a; attr4=val4a |
| attr1=val1b; attr5=val5b; attr3=val3b; attr6=val6b |

I want to resolve this column into :

| attr1 | attr2 | attr3 | attr4 | attr5 | attr6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val1a | val2a | val3a | val4a | Null | Null |
| val1b | Null | val3b | Null | val5b | val6b |

Can someone help me find a way to do this in python.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split each string by `;`, and for each split, split by `=` and convert it into a dict and then use `pd.json_normalize`:

```
new_df = pd.json_normalize(df['name'].str.split(r';\s*').apply(lambda lst: dict(i.split('=') for i in lst)))
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
   attr1  attr2  attr3  attr4  attr5  attr6
0  val1a  val2a  val3a  val4a    NaN    NaN
1  val1b    NaN  val3b    NaN  val5b  val6b
```